# Why do I have this error? MySQLNonTransientConnectionException

Tags: java, android, mysql

I have this error: >com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static int SIGN_IN_CODE = 1;
    private RelativeLayout activity_main;
    private FloatingActionButton sendBtn;


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == SIGN_IN_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Snackbar.make(activity_main, "Вы авторизованы!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //displayAllMessages();
            } else {
                Snackbar.make(activity_main, "Вы не авторизованы!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        activity_main = findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
        sendBtn = findViewById(R.id.btnSend);


        sendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                EditText textField = findViewById(R.id.messageField);

                if (textField.getText().toString().equals(""))
                    return;

                //SQL

                //String connectionStr = "jdbc:mysql://109.95.210.183:3306/u86855_wp11";
                String connectionStr = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/app";
                //String insert = "INSERT INTO u86855_wp11(nick, message) VALUES('lax','petro')";
                String insert = "INSERT INTO users(nick, message) VALUES('lax','petro')";
                try {

                    Object mysql = Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                    //Connection dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionStr,"u86855_wp11", "SchoolApp");
                    Connection dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionStr, "SchoolApp", "SchoolApp");
                    Statement statement = dbConnection.createStatement();
                    ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(insert);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    textField.setText(e.toString());
                    Log.e("Ошибка", "database", e);
                }


                // textField.setText("");
            }

        });

        if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() == null)
            startActivityForResult(AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder().build(), SIGN_IN_CODE);
        else {
            Snackbar.make(activity_main, "Вы авторизованы!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //displayAllMessages();
        }
    }

    private void displayAllMessages() {
    }
    
}
```

Here is my error Log:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:403)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:898)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:887)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:861)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2266)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2015)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:768)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:403)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:385)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:323)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:569)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:219)
    at com.example.databasetest.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:81)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
 Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1448)
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:102)
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:90)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:787)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:188)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:299)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2187)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2220)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2015) 
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:768) 
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334) 
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:403) 
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:385) 
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:323) 
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:569) 
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:219) 
    at com.example.databasetest.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:81) 
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is in the line

`Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` in your Error Log.

It happens when you try to make network call on main thread. You should be using Async task or Rxjava or any other approach for this.

Another approach can be paste this code in your main activity after setcontent view.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new 
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }
```

and import this in your activity file

`import android.os.StrictMode;`